# copypastecoder - What a name?

Tags: discussion, display-names, offensive

I just noticed the name `copypastecoder` on a new [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/275526/copypastecoder).  While this name isn't offensive *per se* it indicates the person has some wrongheaded ideas about programming, and indeed about SO.  Should I just go merrily along my way, or is there a way to send them a gentle nudge about the name?

Comment: Sense of humour transplant, stat!

Comment: Damn it @ceejavoz, I'm a Doctor, not a miracle maker!

Comment: Why does this make you so c.ross?

Comment: I'll take this as a go merrily along my way.

Answer (score 15):

Are you serious? How do you know he isn't being ironic? Why do you think his username is any indication of his approach to coding? What's it got to do with you, anyway?

Answer (score 10):

Just move along.  If that's what they want to be known as, well, then that's what they want.

Comment: Your last name is "garlic" in German (you probably knew that). I have, however, no reason to believe you stink. Case rested and +1.

Comment: Some people say my code stinks.  :-)

Comment: @balpha: I will not sit here at my desk while you decry garlic without typing a strongly worded bold message celebrating its wonderfulness! **Garlic is delicious and smells awesome.**

Comment: If you say so, @Urdnot: **Garlics delirious smell is awful!** Did I get it right?

Comment: @Urdnot: How do you manage to sit at a desk? I was led to believe that you had no legs and lived in a jar.

Comment: I sit with my neck. Klingons can do whatever they want, especially when they are **Krogan**!

Answer (score 6):

I think you're assuming a heck of a lot based on a screen name.

There are plenty of other reasonable explanations about why that name was chosen, none of which are any of our business.